# OMNeT++: Stop execution of simulation with multiple repititions

Tags: omnet++

**OMNeT++ 5.0 with cmdenv:**

Is there a way to stop a running simulation, which consists of **multiple repetitions**?
The *Terminate*-Button only terminates the current iteration, but not the whole simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an issue with the Eclipse version OMNeT++ 5.0 is built on (Eclipse 4.4). OMNeT++ 5.1 will be based on Eclipse 4.6 and it will handle the batch cancellation correctly. OMNeT++ 5.1 pre 2 version should also work.

Comment: Sadly there are still update and progress reporting issues in Eclipse 4.6 that are fixed only in Eclipse 4.7 (but E4.7 will come only in Junew which to late for OMNeT++ 5.1 so we have to live with that for now :( )